# Memory management puzzlement for novice

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

As I'm pretty new to Objective-C and memory management, I was curious if this code was ok -

First of all, code to return a UIImageView -

```
-(UIImageView *)somethingAnimation {

UIImageView *something = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Something.png"]];
something.frame = CGRectMake(-100, -100, kSomethingWidth, kSomethingHeight);

return something; // released later by the Swarmer object

}
```

Then the code which calls it, where UIImageView *something is declared in the interface then this is in the implementation -

```
something = [controller somethingAnimation];
```

and later -

```
[something release];
```

Is this correctly releasing everything? Seems to work without memory or crashing issues. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: That makes the class less reusable. Imagine you share that code with a friend, he calls the somethingAnimation method but doesn't know he has to call release later on. Now he has a memory leak, because he trusted your code to follow the conventions laid out by Apple in their [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) defines a set of naming conventions that determines whether a method should return an "owned" object or an autoreleased one. According to these conventions, a method named `-somethingAnimation` should definitely return an autoreleased object. So in your case, you should be returning `[something autorelease]` instead, and then not releasing it later.

Comment: Does this mean that if I were to call the method "newSomethingAnimation" (as I do want a new animation) it would be ok?

Comment: It'd be better, but still non-standard.  Just return an autoreleased object and let the caller worry about it.  Bifurcating from standard practices is to be avoided.

Comment: Many thanks for your help everyone - I'm re-reading the memory management guide and it's starting to mean something to me now...

Answer (score 2):

It technically works but it's bad practice. You should really autorelease it before you return it. Don't rely on anyone else to know to release it.